# HOW TO Return value array on function php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hy I have code below,
I wanna return value array with function :

```
    <?php

include "config/koneksi.php";

//script1
$fetch1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM orders_temp");

$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch1)){
    $array[] = $row[id_orders_temp];
}
echo "script1: ";
print_r($array);

echo "<br>";

//script2
function cart(){
    $array1= array();

    $fetch2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM orders_temp");

    while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch2)) {
        $array1[] = $r[id_orders_temp];
    }
    return $array1;
}

$cart1 = cart();
echo "script2 : ";
print_r($cart1);


?>
```

and the result :

```
script1: Array ( [0] => 150 [1] => 151 )
script2 : Array ( )
```

there's no problem if I print_r array without function, but
when I used function as above, I got blank array( ). 
How can I get array value with function ?

Comment: should be  `$array[] = $row['id_orders_temp'];`

Comment: no working,variable name between script1 and script2 is different @JigarShah, just focus on script 2 with function

Comment: still not working

Comment: Your connection handler `$conn` is not available in scope of your function. Either use `global` or explicitly pass the connection handler to the function.

Comment: You have a scope issue with your connection in the cart function, you should pass it as an argument to the function (avoid using `global`). If you had enabled error reporting, you would have been notified about it.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul thanks, it works, i've to pass $conn to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$conn` is not defined within the function, so you need to either pass it to the function or reference the globally available `$conn`.

#### Pass in `$conn`

```
include "config/koneksi.php";

function cart($conn) {
    $identifiers = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id_orders_temp FROM orders_temp');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $identifiers[] = $row['id_orders_temp'];
    }

    return $identifiers;
}

$cart = cart($conn);

var_dump($cart);
```

#### Reference global `$conn`

Ideally, you should limit global state (and accessing it), so I would not recommend this.

```
include "config/koneksi.php";

function cart() {
    global $conn;

    $identifiers = array();

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id_orders_temp FROM orders_temp');

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $identifiers[] = $row['id_orders_temp'];
    }

    return $identifiers;
}

$cart = cart();

var_dump($cart);
```

**Note** I have renamed variables within `cart()` and optimized the SQL query to select only those columns actually required.

Comment: thank you so much, I understand now

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable `id_orders_temp`
returning a correct value ??
and if its a column of DB then u have to

```
$row['id_orders_temp'];
```

Comment: Php is smart enough to figure that out on its own, however it will issue a notice

Answer (score -1):

You have to assign the array as a global array because of the scoping inside the array, so replace the first line inside the function with one below:
    $array1 = global $array;